# Reproduce imager::RGBtoHSI with the 'hip' Haskell library

Tags: r, haskell, image-processing

I do this image with the 'hip' library for Haskell (this is a coloring of a complex function):

[image]

Now, when I apply the `RGBtoHSI` function of the R package 'imager' to this image, I obtain this one:

[image]

I'd like to know how to make the second image from the first one with 'hip'. There is a "rgb to hsi" function in 'hip' but it just converts the RGB coordinates to HSI coordinates. I don't know what the R function is doing. I took a look at the code, but it is written in C++ and it depends on a header file of 3Mb. In fact I'd like to know what it does, and maybe I could port it to Haskell. I don't think there's a built-in function in 'hip' for that (I didn't find in the doc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your R version is just a mistyped and crippled version of what you get in also in Haskell/hip with `toPixelHSI`. Specifically, what the R conversion does is generate the hue as an angle (range 0-360) but the other channels in range 0-1. If you save that, it maps the hue angle to the red channel and normalizes to the angles, which means the other channels are squelched to almost exactly zero – too low to be visible, but we can boost them back (though they are of course quantized to only two levels):

[image: R's hsi version with the crippled s and i channels boosted back]

This, without the quantization, is basically what `toPixelHSI` gives you in hip.

If you actually want what you got in R at first – well, the sensible thing is to extract only the hue channel from the HSI pixel, and use any colour map you like on that.

Or, perhaps more insightfully, just take the [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) of the
complex function and plot that as a real-valued function.

Comment: Thanks. I had such a suspicion because the obtained image is always highly red. Could you show how you use `toPixelHSI` to get this image?

Comment: I understand what R does now, but I don't understand how you use `toPixelHSI` to transform an image.

Comment: It should be just `Hip.map (toPixelHSI >>> \(PixelHSI h _ _) -> PixelRGB h 0 0)` or something similar.

Comment: Yes, but this is what R does, no? I'm afraid I misunderstood something. How did you get the image you posted? You just changed the green and the blue channels?

Comment: Yes, I just multiplied them by a large factor

Comment: Ok that's clear now. That makes sense except that this HSI image should not be plottable (as in Haskell, you can get a HSI version but it is not writeable to a file).

Comment: Well, HSI by itself doesn't really make sense for actual images (in particular the jump as the angle flips around). Normally you'd just do some processing on the channels before converting back to RGB. But you _can_ manually take the channels apart as I showed. Only, Haskell forces you to be explicit with the constructors, which IMO is a good thing.

Comment: Yes, I use HSI to construct a color map, by transforming the HSI coordinates and then converting to RGB. But in R, nothing in the image indicates the color space, this is just an array of numbers. So every image is considered as RGB when it comes to plot it.